# How to toggle sidebar when you click on element of them?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following sidenavbar: http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/fancy-sidebar-navigation

All works fine, I implemented to my website, but I want when you click on element of list, the sidenavbar to close, my idea was to add an `id="link-item"` and to add in js file when you click on element the sidenavbar will close. My try to make this:

**First Try:**

```
$('#link-item').click(function () {
  var trigger = $('.hamburger'),
      overlay = $('.overlay'),
      isClosed = false;

  $('#link-item').click(function () {
    hamburger_cross();
  });

  function hamburger_cross() {

    if (isClosed == true) {
      overlay.hide();
      trigger.removeClass('is-open');
      trigger.addClass('is-closed');
      isClosed = false;
    } else {
      overlay.show();
      trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
      trigger.addClass('is-open');
      isClosed = true;
    }
  }

  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
      $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  });
});
```

**Second Try:**

```
trigger.click(function () {
  hamburger_cross();      
});

$('#link-item').click(function () {
  hamburger_cross();      
});
```

Comment: You realise `id="list_item"` and `#link-item` don't match?

Comment: sorry i write wrong the id

Comment: Please provide (a minimal) piece of HTML that relates to this, so it is testable.

Comment: Assigning a click handler inside a click handler (on the same element) is in most situations a bad idea.

Comment: Sorry guys i am tired, in my project the ids are good, i correct the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply let the trigger run on the `nav .sidebar-nav li` elements like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var trigger = $('.hamburger, nav .sidebar-nav li'),
      overlay = $('.overlay'),
     isClosed = false;

    trigger.click(function () {
      hamburger_cross();      
    });

    function hamburger_cross() {

      if (isClosed == true) {          
        overlay.hide();
        trigger.removeClass('is-open');
        trigger.addClass('is-closed');
        isClosed = false;
      } else {   
        overlay.show();
        trigger.removeClass('is-closed');
        trigger.addClass('is-open');
        isClosed = true;
      }
  }

  $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"], nav .sidebar-nav li').click(function () {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
  });  
});
```

---

I think it is a poor implementation though. This does all you need:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var trigger = $('.hamburger, nav .sidebar-nav li');

    trigger.click(function () {
        $('.overlay').toggle();
        trigger.toggleClass('is-open is-closed');
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
    });
});
```

Comment: Your second version works well, i have a little problem with dropdown list, but i resolve i change ``nav .sidebar-nav li`` with an id, and i put the id on ``li`` and on ``dropdown`` i did't put.

Comment: @Sn0pY Please use a class if you are going to use the same ID multiple times, ID's are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

Use in list item `data-toggle="offcanvas"` just like

```
<li>
   <a id="id" data-toggle="offcanvas" href="#">Home</a>
</li>


var trigger = $('.hamburger, #id')
```

Comment: where i add ``var trigger = $('.hamburger, #id')`` in js?

Comment: the sidebar are close but the overlay is not toggled and the button is X not three lines

Comment: also use on list item data-toggle="offcanvas"  just use in example